# error LNK1152: cannot resolve one or more undecorated symbols. How to fix?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, int, linker-errors, lnk

The problem with the problem is, I don't know where the problem exists, so I can't paste all my source codes here.

The error is a LNK error, LNK 1152 to be exact.
I get 3 warnings brought with it:

```
error LNK1152: cannot resolve one or more undecorated symbols   
warning LNK4002: "int __clrcall main(cli::array<class System::String ^ >^)" (?main@@$$HYMHP$01AP$AAVString@System@@@Z) defined in Release\Note Reminder.obj
warning LNK4002: "int __clrcall main(int,char * * const)" (?main@@$$HYMHHQAPAD@Z) defined in Release\INIwriter.obj
warning LNK4022: cannot find unique match for symbol 'main
```

I have NO IDEA how to fix this error.
Someone had this before, and fixed it?

Comment: `The problem with the problem is, I don't know where the problem exists, so I can't paste all my source codes here.` Then you haven't made any attempt at narrowing down the problem to a 10-20 line testcase as one of your first debugging steps, which is unfortunate. Plus, that isn't C++.

Comment: it seems that you have two definitions of the `main` function. One in the object file `Note Reminder.obj` and the other in the file `INIwriter.obj`. Each function with a different signature. The second one seems to be the entry point of the program.

Comment: From the looks of the error messages, *you* may think it's C++, but the compiler/linker think you're using C++/CLI, which is not the same thing. In this case, what the compiler thinks governs how the code will be treated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be C++-CLI or something, not C++. You're defining `main` in more than one object file. You're even told which files those are.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't understand why you get the error, you should start by resolving the warnings, which in this case is pretty straight forward.

`warning LNK4022: cannot find unique match for symbol 'main`

.. You have two `main` functions, remove or rename one of them. this should also resolve your linking error.

Comment: Mm, that'd be hard, because my source is pretty damn big. I can try to use the ctrl + F and search for 'main' but I did already and the only thing I found was the mainDLL.

Comment: How did your source become "pretty damn big" without you noticing that you had conflicting function definitions? Did you not try to run it even once along the way?

Comment: Ye, but I already tried to comment ALL parts, and decomment them bit by bit.. And error stays popping up,
Couldn't it be something in the project properties?

Comment: Or where should I start searching than?

Comment: @Miracle, You have two files `INIwriter.cpp` and `Note Reminder.cpp` which both contains a main function each. So look in those. If you can't find it then there's sadly not much more we can do to help you.